# Show a heading click and move to next screen android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Can anyone help me with code, I am developing an android application and need some help. On a screen called results I need to show the headings of the records in a sqlite database in a view, the heading must be clicked and open a new window to show the full record, A long click must allow the user to delete the record.

This is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main extends Activity {

ListView txtMainList;
// EditText nameTxt,posTxt;
Button saveBtn,retrieveBtn,btnBegin;
ArrayList<String >accidents=new ArrayList<String>();
EditText index;

ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    index=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtRegistrationNo);

    btnBegin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBegin);

    txtMainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.txtMainList);

    Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, accidents);

    final DBHelper newDb=new DBHelper(this);

    accidents.clear();

    Cursor c=newDb.getYVAllData();

    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        accidents.add("Accident Number : "+c.getString(0));
    }

    txtMainList.setAdapter(Adapter);
    newDb.close();

    txtMainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View agr1, int index, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), accidents.get(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: I've added my code so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using listview you can use longClickListener.

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id) {
                //Delete record

                return true;
            }
        });
```

and add android:longClickable="true" to your listview item layout.

Onclick:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        //Show full record in pop up           
    }
});
```